# How to configure multiple services/containers in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, microservices, docker-for-windows

I am new to Docker and Kubernetes.
Technologies used:

- Dotnet Core 2.2
- Asp.NET Core WebAPI 2.2
- Docker for windows(Edge) with Kubernetes support enabled
- [Code](https://github.com/vkgpt11/StackOverFlowSuppot/tree/master/DotnetCore)

I am having two services hosted into two docker containers container1 and container2.

Below is my deploy.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapi-dockerkube
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapi-dockerkube
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapi-dockerkube
        image: "webapidocker:latest"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/values
            port: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/values
            port: 80
      - name: webapi-dockerkube2
        image: "webapidocker2:latest"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/other/values
            port: 80
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/other/values
            port: 80
```

When I am running command:

```
kubectl create -f .\deploy.yaml
```

I am getting status as `CrashLoopBackOff`.

But same is running fine when i have only one container configured.
When checking logs I am getting following error:
`Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for pod webapi-dockerkube-8658586998-9f8mk, choose one of: [webapi-dockerkube webapi-dockerkube2]`

Comment: Can you post last lines of  "kubectl logs -p POD_NAME" of crashlooping pod?

Comment: Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for pod webapi-dockerkube-8658586998-9f8mk, choose one of: [webapi-dockerkube webapi-dockerkube2]

Comment: ok, you need to specify one of containers:
"kubectl logs -p POD_NAME webapi-dockerkube"
or
"kubectl logs -p POD_NAME webapi-dockerkube2"

Comment: for both Error from server (NotFound): pods "POD_NAME" not found

Comment: you can get your pod names by running `kubectl get po` there you will see pod name similar to webapi-dockerkube-xxxx. Replace POD_NAME with that name.

Comment: I am getting only one name and output of that is:`Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for pod webapi-dockerkube-8658586998-9f8mk, choose one of: [webapi-dockerkube webapi-dockerkube2] `

Comment: use `kubectl logs pod webapi-dockerkube-8658586998-9f8mk -c webapi-dockerkube` and then ` kubectl logs pod webapi-dockerkube-8658586998-9f8mk -c webapi-dockerkube2`

Comment: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:80: address already in use. ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address already in use
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()

Comment: I think something to do with port

Comment: I have run this command `kubectl logs -f webapi-dockerkube-8658586998-vwrnq -c webapi-dockerkube`

Comment: I have changed the port of second container from 80 to 8081 but error is still `http://[::]:80: address already in use. ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Address already in use at `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running two containers in the same pod which bind both to port 80. This is not possible within the same pod.
Think of a pod like a 'server' and you can't have two processes bind to the same port.

Solution in your situation: Use different ports inside the pod or use separate pods. From your deployment there seems to be no shared resources like filesystem, so it would be easy to split the containers to separate pods.

Note that it will not suffice to change the pod definition if you want to have both containers running in the same pod with different ports. The application in the container must bind to a different port as well.

Comment: I think the same discussion already going on in comments please read that and provide your feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html

  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

> here sharing example for multi container you can use this template

Also you can check for logs of using

> Kubectl logs

Check reason for crashloop back